# For what natural reasons can dragon die?

Tags: dragons, death, anatomy

very recently I read story collection dedicated to dragons (all stories inside were about various forms of dragons). And one of those stories (and also epilogues) inspired me for following question:

**For what natural reasons can dragon die? (excepting age)**

---

**Base:**

Let's say that dragon will not meet anyone who would like to kill him/her, or will be lucky to survive all those battles with people who would like to kill him/her.

And his/her death will be natural.

**Story mention:**

In that story king's son revolts against father and traditions and resolved to bring honor back to his family by killing of dragon.

However, the first dragon he meet, dies for heart attack (heart infarct). From description it can be deduced that it was (more or less) for age.

**Background:**

I could ask only for option of dragon's death for heart attack. But I rather decided to generalise it to any natural reason that may bring dragon to death.

Comment: This is your story. You can make dragons susceptible to many diseases and vulnerable to elements, make them die of poisoning, starvation or "mana drain".

Comment: I assume Dragons act and behave like a biological animal and there is no function of their natural being that is magical in anyway.   Everything is perfectly biologically sound as we know it today (well, okay, the issue of flight is physics more than biology, I'm talking more about it's life cycle.).

Comment: Without having any specifics about how your dragons function, we can't really be specific. It's essentially "old age" and "disease". The same as any other living thing. You can also have, say, malnutrition, accidents, and so on. Again, similar to any other living thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Death integral to reproduction.**

Sort of boring to have dragons die for the reasons people do - infected toe, boating accidents, land mine.  Yah, yah.

If things go well, people do not routinely die during reproduction but a lot of animals routinely do.  Ideas:

1:  Phoenix.  The dragon immolates itself on laying eggs.  The fire is needed to make the eggs hatch.  Or possibly new dragon is inside old dragon, and the old stuff burns away to reveal the new.

2:  Salmon.  Dragons die after they mate and lay eggs.  Their decaying bodies are useful to the offspring as a refuge or to attract prey.

3:  Nourishment.  Baby dragons eat parent from the inside out, like wasp larvae.  Or eat the parent after they hatch.  Or female eats male, mantis style.